# SAS Loop over a list of variables inside a macro (read one each time)

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would need to do a loop over a list of variables inside a macro.

The list is created in the following way (I have started the name of the variables that I want with MO, nu or KA):

```
proc sql noprint; 
   select name into :varsi separated by ' ' 
   from dictionary.columns 
   where libname eq 'LABIMP' and  memname eq 'MUESTRA1' 
     and (NAME LIKE 'MO_%' OR NAME LIKE 'nu_%' or name like 'KA_%'); 
quit;
```

Then, I need to run a macro for each one... this macro is inside the following data step:

```
data labimp.muestra1;
   set labimp.muestra1;
   counter + 1;
   by nnumero_de_cliente;
   if first.nnumero_de_cliente then counter = 1;
   %addTendency(&varsi);
run;
```

Of course this way **is not working because it brings all the variables at the same time**. It's important that if I need a loop must remain inside the other datastep.....

I know it should be easy by I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to design your `proc sql` step to create all of those macro calls.

```
proc sql ; 
select cats('%addTendency(',name,')'
  into :tendencyList separated by ' ' 
  from dictionary.columns 
  where libname eq 'LABIMP' and  memname eq 'MUESTRA1' 
  and (NAME LIKE 'MO_%' OR NAME LIKE 'nu_%' or name like 'KA_%'); 
quit;
```

That creates a list of %addTendency() calls that you then call by referencing &tendencyList (which I named, but you can name otherwise):

```
data labimp.muestra1;
set labimp.muestra1;

counter + 1;
by nnumero_de_cliente;
if first.nnumero_de_cliente then counter = 1;

&tendencyList.

run;
```

Comment: This method is the easiest to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&varsi));
  %addTendency(%scan(&varsi, &i));
%end;
```