# Update Excel output using ODS?

Tags: sas, sas-macro, sas-ods

I am running a macro program to analyze a data set. In the end of my macro, i used a ODS statement and a proc Report to export my results. What i want is: For each time i run the macro program with a new data set, the results will be updated in a new sheet in the same Excel file, without delete the sheets of the old data sets, nor the old Excel file. Please help me.

Comment: of possible interest: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/143-2013.pdf

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Thank you but i think it works only if i run all my ODS statement in the same macro , before i close the main ODS. What i want is to update a Excel file after closing the macro program and the ODS statement.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 In the page 2 of the doc, it said that we cannot use the techniques described in the paper to update the existing workbook.

Comment: Right - hence my comment, not an answer.  You might be forced to read in all sheets, store the old sheets in .work, then re-export those old sheets along with the new sheets and overwrite the Excel file.  Thus effectively adding a new sheet.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Can you tell me which proc or statement should i use in order to do that please?

Answer (score 1):

The basic way to approach this is to have the main `ods tagsets.excelxp` statement outside of the macro iterations.  Then only control the sheet inside the macro.

Say you have:

```
%macro run_me(sheet=,sex=);
  ods tagsets.excelxp options(sheet_name="&sheet.");
  proc print data=sashelp.class;
    where sex="&sex.";
  run;
%mend run_me;

ods tagsets.excelxp file="c:\temp\test.xml";
  %run_me(sheet=Male,sex=M);
  %run_me(sheet=Female,sex=F);
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

You just have to be careful with your output in the rest of the analysis; you may need to use `ods select` statements like so:

```
ods tagsets.excelxp select none;
```

at the start of the macro, and then when you want to start outputting again

```
ods tagsets.excelxp select all;
```

(Or just select the specific output you want, of course.)

Comment: Thank you Joe. I think we are close. But i'm wonder if we can make the code more automatic? For example: In the macro run_me, i will remove the Where Statement, and add a macro variable for the data_input: run_me(sheet= , data_input=). Then in the next ODS tagsets statement, i don't want to repeat manually the %run_me for all my data sets. So If i have a library that contains all my data sets, does SAS have a function that will analyze automatically all the data sets in that library, one by one?

Comment: For example, if we can count the number of data sets in a library, then call each data set in that library by its order (1 2 3 4...), that will allow us to do a loop.

Comment: Ok i found it, i test the code then i will update the question if i found the answer.

Comment: You can certainly do what you say; there's not a built in SAS function to do that, but you can generate macro calls from a dataset, or from SAS's metadata.

Comment: For example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722069/loop-over-a-list-of-variables-inside-a-macro-read-one-each-time/22722907#22722907) shows one way to do so.